# Merging 2 datasets using sql?

Tags: python, sql, r, ms-access, merge

Im doing a data management on a dataset to train my self.
I have two tables the first one is called "Suivi" and the second one "Treatement", i wanna merge the next 2 tables in way to get the third one.

Suivi Table:

| Suivi_id | member_id | rhinitis_symptoms | medicin_id1 | medicin_id2 | medicin_id3 | medicin_id4 | medicin_id5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3357195 | 85763 | 51 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3357665 | 87339 | 8 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3358237 | 87343 | 17 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3358319 | 87345 | 26 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3358893 | 87343 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3359371 | 87343 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3360505 | 87343 | 30 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3362165 | 87345 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3362607 | 87343 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3362613 | 87505 | 64 |  |  |  |  |  |

Treatment :

| Treatement_id | suivi_data_id | medicin_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 927231 | 3357195 | 7501 |
| 927765 | 3357665 | 7489 |
| 928423 | 3358237 | 7489 |
| 928425 | 3358237 | 7501 |
| 928427 | 3358237 | 7623 |
| 928539 | 3358319 | 7489 |
| 929173 | 3358893 | 7489 |
| 929741 | 3359371 | 7489 |
| 931089 | 3360505 | 7489 |
| 932937 | 3362165 | 7489 |
| 933381 | 3362607 | 7569 |
| 933383 | 3362607 | 7645 |
| 933385 | 3362607 | 7789 |
| 933387 | 3362607 | 19159 |
| 933393 | 3362613 | 7569 |
| 933395 | 3362613 | 7605 |
| 933397 | 3362613 | 7645 |
| 933399 | 3362613 | 7789 |
| 933401 | 3362613 | 19159 |

The wanted table :

| Suivi_id | member_id | rhinitis_symptoms | medicin_id1 | medicin_id2 | medicin_id3 | medicin_id4 | medicin_id5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3357195 | 85763 | 51 | 7501 |  |  |  |  |
| 3357665 | 87339 | 8 | 7489 |  |  |  |  |
| 3358237 | 87343 | 17 | 7489 | 7501 | 7623 |  |  |
| 3358319 | 87345 | 26 | 7489 |  |  |  |  |
| 3358893 | 87343 | 0 | 7489 |  |  |  |  |
| 3359371 | 87343 | 0 | 7489 |  |  |  |  |
| 3360505 | 87343 | 30 | 7489 |  |  |  |  |
| 3362165 | 87345 | 4 | 7489 |  |  |  |  |
| 3362607 | 87343 | 0 | 7569 | 7645 | 7789 | 19159 |  |
| 3362613 | 87505 | 64 | 7569 | 7605 | 7645 | 7789 | 19159 |

Is there a way to do it in sql (in access ?!) or by doing a function in R or python.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a join.

Something like:

```
SELECT suivi.Suivi_id, suivi.member_id, treatment.medicin_id ...
FROM suivi
JOIN treatment ON suivi.Suivi_id = treatment.suivi_data_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways. Either with the Pivot Function(https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) or
rank your data with the ROW_NUMMBER() function  in mssql. (Other dbs should have similar functions.) It is also possible to write something dynamic, but here the staitc version:

```
WITH TreatementRowNumber as (
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [suivi_data_id]  ORDER BY [suivi_data_id])     RowNumber
, suivi_data_id
, medicin_id
FROM Treatement

)

Select
[Suivi_id]
, [member_id]
, [rhinitis_symptoms]
, (SELECT Medicin_id FROM TreatementRowNumber WHERE Suivi.Suivi_id = TreatementRowNumber.suivi_data_id AND RowNumber = 1) medicin_id1
, (SELECT Medicin_id FROM TreatementRowNumber WHERE Suivi.Suivi_id = TreatementRowNumber.suivi_data_id AND RowNumber = 2) medicin_id2
, (SELECT Medicin_id FROM TreatementRowNumber WHERE Suivi.Suivi_id = TreatementRowNumber.suivi_data_id AND RowNumber = 3) medicin_id3
, (SELECT Medicin_id FROM TreatementRowNumber WHERE Suivi.Suivi_id = TreatementRowNumber.suivi_data_id AND RowNumber = 4) medicin_id4
, (SELECT Medicin_id FROM TreatementRowNumber WHERE Suivi.Suivi_id = TreatementRowNumber.suivi_data_id AND RowNumber = 5) medicin_id5
 
FROM Suivi
```

Comment: i never used MSSQL i will try to see if it works. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Python Solution using pandas:

Here I am using `pandas merge function` to concat two tables namely `Suivi_Table` and `Treatment_Table`. Next, to identify similar column of both tables `Renaming` column `suivi_data_id` to `Suivi_id`,. Next mentioning the column names in `[[]]` which I wanted to select from Treatment table.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(Suivi_Table, Treatment_Table.rename(columns = {'suivi_data_id':'Suivi_id'})[['Suivi_id','medicin_id']], on="Suivi_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to merge them, however, you would be best using a full join.  Given that you have suivi_id and suivi_data_id, I'd join on these, and you should hopefully end up with each treatment id for each record:

```
SELECT *
FROM suivi as s
FULL OUTER JOIN treatment as t ON s.Suivi_id = t.suivi_data_id
```